# How to keep row position same when zoom your browser more than 100% using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have small issue with bootstrap grid system , I have a row that has grid setup with two sections with col-md-6 , Now problem is when i zoom my browser more than 100% my Close label and input is moving to next line. I want them to stay same place all the time zoom should not effect the position of the rows.I tried to use col-xs-1 but it does not work. How can i achieve that task using bootstrap ?

main.html

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="container col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-5">Actual Cycle Start:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <input class="form-control" ng-model="riskAssessmentDTO.cycleStartDate"
                                         k-format="'MM/dd/yyyy'" disabled />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-1">
                                    <label class="control-label"> Close:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-5 changeWdh">
                                    <input class="form-control" ng-model="riskAssessmentDTO.cycleEndDate" k-format="'MM/dd/yyyy'" disabled />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 fieldHeight">
                    <label for="challengeOutstand" class="col-md-5">Challenges
                        Outstanding:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="challengeOutstand"
                            name="challengeOutstand" maxlength="256"
                            ng-model="riskAssessmentDTO.challengesOutstanding" disabled />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

main.css

```
.changeWdh{  
    width: 152px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6-md">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                        <label class="col-md-5">Actual Cycle Start:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <input class="form-control" ng-model="riskAssessmentDTO.cycleStartDate"
                                     k-format="'MM/dd/yyyy'" disabled />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                        <label class="control-label"> Close:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5 changeWdh">
                       <input class="form-control" ng-model="riskAssessmentDTO.cycleEndDate" k-format="'MM/dd/yyyy'" disabled />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 fieldHeight">
        <label for="challengeOutstand" class="col-xs-5">Challenges
                    Outstanding:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="challengeOutstand"
                        name="challengeOutstand" maxlength="256"
                        ng-model="riskAssessmentDTO.challengesOutstanding" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

place your col-5 and col-1 into row div's or make them both into xs, not one md and one xs, and place them into a div container class "col-md-6"

Comment: I tried your solution and also edited my question please look at it , it does not solve my problem.

Comment: when you say you want them to stay in the same place, what do you mean?

Comment: it should not move to next line when i zoom browser +

Comment: meaning the label and input should stay on the same line?

Comment: @aftab I just editted my answer, check to see if it works, I organized it a bit better

Comment: I really appreciate you are helping me but its still moving input to next line when i zoom to 110%